# Using OpenGL from ArrayFire

Tags: c++, opengl, opencl, arrayfire

If I have an af::array A already in GPU memory, what is the procedure to pass it through to OpenGl? My intention is to plot it as a line graph using OpenGl, but I'm not sure how to deal with the fact that the backend of Arrayfire could be OpenCl, CUDA or even the CPU. How does OpenGl achieve ownership of the array? I would preferably like to avoid copying if possible.

On a separate note, if I was to use the in built forge library to plot graphs in Arrayfire, I find that if I follow the tutorials to plot a graph, by pressing and holding on the data in the plot and dragging it somewhere else, the data plot moves from its original location and is no longer correctly aligned with the axis. Is there a way to correct this?

Comment: You need at least two shaders, vertex and fragment. If you'r array is GLBuffer vertex data use it in your shaders.  Suggesting David_Wolff OpenGL4 Shading Language Cookbook. This is a kind of `Modern OpenGL RedBook`.

Comment: @VictorGubin I am aware of how to use OpenGL on its own, I would like to know how to fill an OpenGL buffer with an array of information, derived from what I have in Arrayfire, without needing unnecessary copies to set the OpenGL buffer.

Comment: [Sharing OpenCL and OpenGL data](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Performance/Conceptual/OpenCL_MacProgGuide/shareGroups/shareGroups.html)

Comment: And build with OpenCL.  [BUILD_OPENCL](https://github.com/arrayfire/arrayfire/wiki/Build-Instructions-for-OSX#opencl-build-dependencies) using cmake.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@HamzaAB

What you are asking is known as GL-CUDA or GL-OpenCL interoperability, if you already don't know about it, which is the area [Forge](https://github.com/arrayfire/forge) tries to address. You can look the [ComputeCopy.h](https://github.com/arrayfire/forge/blob/master/include/ComputeCopy.h) header inside forge repository to understand how to do OpenGL interop.

Having said that, Do you want to reset the transformation you are doing to the line plot, if you want to reset it then there is way. While holding the left control, hit middle mouse button, that will reset the pan/zoom done to the line plot. If you are facing some other issue with forge's line plot, you may raise an issue [here](https://github.com/arrayfire/forge/issues) and we will try to look into it.

PS. I am one of the core developers of ArrayFire.